# Can you give me good examples of non-convex functions that are problematic for optimization?

Tags: convexity, global-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to test my extended gradient descent algorithm, whose aim is to handle non-convex problems better. Can you give me some examples of non-convex functions that are hard to minimize via gradient descent or heavy-ball methods? I will try to use these functions for testing purposes.

Comment: Standard test problems include https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function and for many more see http://www.geatbx.com/download/GEATbx_ObjFunExpl_v37.pdf

Answer (score 4):

A less-known example is $f(x):=x^2+\exp(-1/(100(x-1))^2)-1$ on the closed interval $[-2,2]$. It takes $-.0067419337989203 $ at $x = .996387676055289 $.
[image]
See [that discussion](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/80976-Max-Value-Of-A-Continuous-Function-On#answer81433) in MaplePrimes for more details.